# FOSUserBundle send mail via console

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

In FOSUserBundle we can create new user via console with command:

```
$ php app/console fos:user:create testuser test@example.com p@ssword
```

Is it possible to send email (via console) created user to activate account? Something like that:

```
$ php app/console fos:user:create testuser test@example.com p@ssword --send-mail
```

If I manually create accounts is it possible to send email to all users, asking them to activate account?

Comment: Create a custom command ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html

Comment: That might work. I'll try.

Comment: You could override that command adding the functionality you need. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595261/override-symfony2-console-commands