# Overriding FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, command-line, overriding, fosuserbundle

I want to override FOSUserBundle so that I can add extra fields(name,avatar,...) to user entity .

I also want to create a command like `fos:user:create` for creating user,so I create `createUserCommand.php` and override `UserManipulator.php` but when runnig command it comes with this error **Column 'name' cannot be null**
I think I must override UserInteface,UserManager and ...
But in this way I have to  override almost whole FOSUserBundle !!
Is there any good tutorial that explain how to do this job ?

**Symp/UserBundle/Util/UsertManipulator**

```
<?php

namespace Symp\UserBundle\Util;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;


class UserManipulator
{
    /**
     * User manager
     *
     * @var UserManagerInterface
     */
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a user and returns it.
     *
     * @param string  $username
     * @param string  $password
     * @param string  $email
     * @param Boolean $active
     * @param Boolean $superadmin
     *
     * @return \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface
     */
    public function create($username, $password, $email, $active, $superadmin,$name)
    {

        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setName($name);
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setPlainPassword($password);
        $user->setEnabled((Boolean) $active);
        $user->setSuperAdmin((Boolean) $superadmin);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Activates the given user.
     *
     * @param string $username
     */
    public function activate($username)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('User identified by "%s" username does not exist.', $username));
        }
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * Deactivates the given user.
     *
     * @param string $username
     */
    public function deactivate($username)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('User identified by "%s" username does not exist.', $username));
        }
        $user->setEnabled(false);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * Changes the password for the given user.
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function changePassword($username, $password)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('User identified by "%s" username does not exist.', $username));
        }
        $user->setPlainPassword($password);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * Promotes the given user.
     *
     * @param string $username
     */
    public function promote($username)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('User identified by "%s" username does not exist.', $username));
        }
        $user->setSuperAdmin(true);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * Demotes the given user.
     *
     * @param string $username
     */
    public function demote($username)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('User identified by "%s" username does not exist.', $username));
        }
        $user->setSuperAdmin(false);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * Adds role to the given user.
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $role
     *
     * @return Boolean true if role was added, false if user already had the role
     */
    public function addRole($username, $role)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('User identified by "%s" username does not exist.', $username));
        }
        if ($user->hasRole($role)) {
            return false;
        }
        $user->addRole($role);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Removes role from the given user.
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $role
     *
     * @return Boolean true if role was removed, false if user didn't have the role
     */
    public function removeRole($username, $role)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('User identified by "%s" username does not exist.', $username));
        }
        if (!$user->hasRole($role)) {
            return false;
        }
        $user->removeRole($role);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Symp/UserBundle/Command/CreateUserCommand**

```
<?php


namespace Symp\UserBundle\Command;

use FOS\UserBundle\Command\CreateUserCommand as BaseCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;


class CreateUserCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('symp:user:create')
            ->setDescription('Create a user.')
            ->setDefinition(array(
                new InputArgument('name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The name of user'),
                new InputArgument('username', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The username'),
                new InputArgument('email', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The email'),
                new InputArgument('password', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The password'),
                new InputOption('super-admin', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Set the user as super admin'),
                new InputOption('inactive', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Set the user as inactive'),
            ))
            ->setHelp(<<<EOT
The <info>fos:user:create</info> command creates a user:

  <info>php app/console fos:user:create matthieu</info>

This interactive shell will ask you for an email and then a password.

You can alternatively specify the email and password as the second and third arguments:

  <info>php app/console fos:user:create matthieu matthieu@example.com mypassword</info>

You can create a super admin via the super-admin flag:

  <info>php app/console fos:user:create admin --super-admin</info>

You can create an inactive user (will not be able to log in):

  <info>php app/console fos:user:create thibault --inactive</info>

EOT
            );
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $name   = $input->getArgument('name');
        $username   = $input->getArgument('username');
        $email      = $input->getArgument('email');
        $password   = $input->getArgument('password');
        $inactive   = $input->getOption('inactive');
        $superadmin = $input->getOption('super-admin');

        $manipulator = $this->getContainer()->get('symp_user.util.user_manipulator');
        $manipulator->create($username, $password, $email, !$inactive, $superadmin,$name);

        $output->writeln(sprintf('Created user <comment>%s</comment>', $username));
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if (!$input->getArgument('name')){
            $name = $this->getHelper('dialog')->askAndValidate(
                $output,
                'Please choose a name: ',
                function($name){
                    if(empty($name)){
                        throw new \Exception('Name can not be empty');
                    }
                }
            );
            $input->setArgument('name',$name);
        }
        parent::interact($input,$output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your command and user manipulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because `$name` is never set.  In the following `$name` is passed to the manipulator with a setter; `$name` does not appear in the argument list.

Instead try this:

#### services.yml

```
app.user_manipulator:
    class:      AppBundle\Tools\UserManipulator
    arguments:  [@fos_user.user_manager]
```

#### CreateUserCommand modification

```
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question;

/**
 * @author Matthieu Bontemps <matthieu@knplabs.com>
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Luis Cordova <cordoval@gmail.com>
 */
class CreateUserCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
                ->setName('app:user:create')
                ->setDescription('Create a user.')
                ->setDefinition(array(
                    new InputArgument('username', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'A username'),
                    new InputArgument('name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'A name'),
                    new InputArgument('email', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An email'),
                    new InputArgument('password', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'A password'),
                    new InputOption('inactive', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Set the user as inactive'),
                    new InputOption('superadmin', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Set the user as superadmin'),
                ))
                ->setHelp(<<<EOT
The <info>app:user:create</info> command creates a user:

  <info>php app/console app:user:create bborko</info>

This interactive shell will ask you for ...

EOT
        );
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $username = $input->getArgument('username');
        $name = $input->getArgument('name');
        $email = $input->getArgument('email');
        $password = $input->getArgument('password');
        $inactive = $input->getOption('inactive');
        $superadmin = $input->getOption('superadmin');

        $manipulator = $this->getContainer()->get('app.user_manipulator');
        $manipulator->setName($name);
        $manipulator->create($username, $password, $email, !$inactive, $superadmin);

        $output->writeln(sprintf('Created user <comment>%s</comment>', $username));
    }

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $helper = $this->getHelper('question');

        if (!$input->getArgument('username')) {
            $question = new Question('Please enter a username: ');
            $question->setValidator(function ($answer) {
                if (empty($answer)) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException(
                    'A username is required'
                    );
                }
                return $answer;
            });
            $question->setMaxAttempts(2);

            $input->setArgument('username', $helper->ask($input, $output, $question));
        }

        if (!$input->getArgument('name')) {
            $question = new Question('Please enter a name: ');
            $question->setValidator(function ($answer) {
                if (empty($answer)) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException(
                    'A name is required'
                    );
                }
                return $answer;
            });
            $question->setMaxAttempts(2);

            $input->setArgument('name', $helper->ask($input, $output, $question));
        }

        if (!$input->getArgument('email')) {
            $question = new Question('Please enter an email: ');
            $question->setValidator(function ($answer) {
                if (empty($answer)) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException(
                    'An e-mail address is required'
                    );
                }
                return $answer;
            });
            $question->setMaxAttempts(2);

            $input->setArgument('email', $helper->ask($input, $output, $question));
        }

        if (!$input->getArgument('password')) {
            $question = new Question('Please enter a password: ');
            $question->setValidator(function ($answer) {
                if (empty($answer)) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException(
                    'A password is required'
                    );
                }
                return $answer;
            });
            $question->setMaxAttempts(5);

            $input->setArgument('password', $helper->ask($input, $output, $question));
        }

    }

}
```

#### UserManipulator

```
namespace AppBundle\Tools;


use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Util\UserManipulator as Manipulator;

/**
 * Executes some manipulations on the users
 *
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 * @author Luis Cordova <cordoval@gmail.com>
 */
class UserManipulator extends Manipulator
{

    /**
     * User manager
     *
     * @var UserManagerInterface
     */
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a user and returns it.
     *
     * @param string  $username
     * @param string  $password
     * @param string  $email
     * @param Boolean $active
     * @param Boolean $superadmin
     *
     * @return \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface
     */
    public function create($username, $password, $email, $active, $superadmin)
    {

        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $user->setName($this->name);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setPlainPassword($password);
        $user->setEnabled((Boolean) $active);
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user, true);

        return $user;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tank you @geoB , I try this but same error ocured :(

Comment: I have edited my answer with a solution just created in a fresh bundle that is confirmed to work.  Let me know if you can make this fly in your airspace.

Comment: I just tried this and got: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "app.user_manipulator"...