# check if email has been sent from fos_userBudle

Tags: symfony, email, fosuserbundle

I used the great fos_userbundle for my users, I can say it work great but there is a case when I want to create my user from command that require to click the link from email for activation, sometimes the successfully message is shown but the email is not sent. So how to check if the email is sent.
Note:
- On my user form interface It work good.
- I use FOSUserBundle dev-master , SF 2.8 , Ubuntu OS, and gmail account.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While using this command:

```
php bin/console fos:user:create testuser test@example.com p@ssword
```

The e-mail activation won't be send. There is no code responsible for sending emails. Used code while running this command:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Command/CreateUserCommand.php#L69

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Util/UserManipulator.php#L48

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Doctrine/UserManager.php#L93

When you want to send activation email after creating user by command, you should overwrite already existing command. In the link below there is some useful info.

[Override symfony2 console commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595261/override-symfony2-console-commands)